# Selecting data based on row index and cell value on Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (df):

```
    a   b   c   d
0   G1  G2  G3  G4
1   1   2   3   4
```

I'd like to get the whole column data based on certain cell index (0) and cell content (G3) value:

input:

```
search("G3", df, 0)
```

output something like:

```
["c", "G3", 3]
```

How would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you can transpose your dataframe first and then do some simple compares:

```
In [14]: df.T[df.T[0] == 'G3']
Out[14]: 
    0  1
c  G3  3
```

Comment: Nice! How do you reach name c in this example? I get some object, and can't figure out go further... df.T[df.T[0] == 'G3'][0..3][0] seems to work for cells...